# Issue while creating tables in magento installer

Tags: magento-1.6

I created one extension and when i test it on other versions , it give me error

```
Error in file: "/var/www/mage_sample/app/code/local/MYD/Module/sql/findyoursize_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1.
```

when i try the same code in sql it works.Can anyone helps where the problem is ? I try so much and stuck now.
Below is my installer code :

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('dimensions')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('dimensions')} (                            
              `dimension_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,        
              `label` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,                     
              `code` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,                      
              PRIMARY KEY (`dimension_id`)                           
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable(`standards`)};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable(`standards`)} (                    
            `standards_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,        
             `name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,                      
             PRIMARY KEY (`standards_id`)                           
           ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable(`standards_values`)};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable(`standards_values`)} (                                                                                                       
                   `standards_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,                    
                    `value` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,                      
                    `order` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,                            
                    `value_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,              
                    UNIQUE KEY `value_id` (`value_id`),                     
                    KEY `FK_standards_values` (`standards_id`)              
                  ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1              

 insert  into  {$this->getTable('dimensions')}(`dimension_id`,`label`,`code`) values (1,'Chest','chest');
insert  into `dimensions`(`dimension_id`,`label`,`code`) values (2,'Waist','waist');
insert  into `dimensions`(`dimension_id`,`label`,`code`) values (3,'Inseam ','inseam ');
insert  into `dimensions`(`dimension_id`,`label`,`code`) values (4,'Hips','hips');
insert  into `dimensions`(`dimension_id`,`label`,`code`) values (5,'Thigh','thigh');
insert  into `dimensions`(`dimension_id`,`label`,`code`) values (6,'Weight','weight');
insert  into `dimensions`(`dimension_id`,`label`,`code`) values (8,'Neck','neck');");


$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Oh come on!....is this a real question? Did you try to look for the problem?

Comment: @Marius i also didn't think that it is a problem but after spending whole day running these queries ,now i think it is.

Comment: @Marius when i remove standards and standards_values tables from qurey than it works.it means issue is in two tables.

Comment: Please try this: http://pastie.org/private/vqrnnow5segrlkzcfo9kg

Please use a file comparison tool to see the differences for a more accurate detail of what was wrong, but you were not using the correct quotes in a few places, and you need `'s around the table name as well, not only the column names.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a `;` after the sql for creating the table `standards_values`

Comment: No i try this also but not succeed.Do this work for you ? As i think issue is in standard table.if i run this query with some other tables before standard that runs and created in database,but query fails on standard.